# In a Hbase Cluster Is it advisable to have a ZooKeeper quorum peer on a node that runs a RegionServer?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have a 4 node hadoop cluster.

> namenode.example.com
>
> datanode1.example.com
>
> datanode2.example.com
>
> datanode3.example.com

- To have a HBase cluster setup on top of this, I intend to use
  **namenode.example.com** as the hbase master and the 3 datanodes as the region servers.
- A fully distributed HBase production setup needs
  greater than 1 zookeeper server , and an odd number is recommended.


  Hence what would be the disadvantages of having zookeeper servers colocated with the regionservers ?

  **References**

  http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_cluster_deploy.html

  http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/zookeeper.html